# ios horizontal auto layout with buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, layout

i want to learn auto layout and apply it in my project. i have a `UIViewController` which looks like [this](http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/8127/h2u.png)
i want to have that view when the device is in landscape but in **landscape** it looks like [this one](http://img90.imageshack.us/img90/6001/4ln5.png)
actually in landscape i centered the buttons with code but i want to do it without using any code. how can i do that ?

Comment: Are you using .xib file for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as follows to get what you want:

1.add a transparent subView on the view, and set auto layout to make it horizontal centered

2.add constraints to make every button a fixed value from transparent subView

3.when the orientation changes, transparent subView always horizontal centered

4.buttons keep the same distance from transparent subView, and it looks like your second view.

Comment: @yourmingfaiz thanks for suggesstion. i did something similar what u suggested already and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

First you must tick auto-layout on. Next you must move the first button to the left until there is a blue line connecting it from the left side of the view. Do the same to the right button except to the right side. Next connect the 2nd button to the 1st and the 3rd to the 2nd. Last the 4th to the 3rd. If you have any problems write a comment.

Comment: i connect all buttons with each other with Horizontal Spacing already as u described but my problem is when the device is landscape i cant align that buttons horizontally to the superview

Comment: @user619712 You want the buttons centered?

Answer (score 0):

Click on story board and change the orientation to landscape
Change supported orientations to landscape too.